# Is there a difference between using export default vs. export default DefineComponent in Vue 3 with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, frontend, vue-component

I'm creating some basic Vue 3 components and I noticed that most of the time I can use either

```
export default {
  ...
};
```

or

```
export default defineComponent({
  ...
});
```

On the [Vue 3 documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#definecomponent), I see that with Define Component you can define types within the constructor.

If I'm making a very basic component with no need for types like this, is there any difference between using `export default` vs `defineComponent`? Which one is preferred?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

TS won't allow you to use `this` type without `defineComponent` or `any` or harder things

```
export let a = {
  data: () => ({ a: 1 }),
  methods: {
    x() {
      this.a
      // ^! Property 'a' does not exist on type '{ x(): void; }'.(2339)
    },
    y(this: { a: number }) {
      this.a // this works
    }
  }
}
```

In JS almost no, defineComponent is a no-op (`e => e`)